# How I can create an interval column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I hav a data frame like :

```
name1       name2    mounth 
 A            B        01
 B            C        02
 A            B        02
 A            B        04
 B            C        03
```

I want to creat a column that shows interval for each pair of names:

```
name1        name2     interval 
 A            B        [1,2];[4,4]
 B            C        [2,3]
```

Is it possible to create interval like above column  in pandas ?

Comment: It's difficult to make the connection between the two dataframes. Can you elaborate on what you want? Dataframes also can't have semi-colon separated values in it, unless you intend to store the intervals as a string which is a bad idea.

Comment: I want to know if it is possible to create a column of intervals in pandas , not from two data frames , I have one data frame ,I want to groupby on the name1 and name 2 (it means aggregation of all rows that name1 and name2 are he same names ) , the interval column represents the interval of the months .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is hard to understand why you need this ...

```
from itertools import chain

df.groupby(['name1','name2']).mounth.\
   apply(lambda x :x.groupby(x.diff().ne(1).cumsum()).\
     apply(lambda y: list(chain.from_iterable([y])) if len(y)>1 else 
         list(chain.from_iterable([y,y])))).\
            groupby(level=['name1','name2']).apply(list)
Out[1305]: 
name1  name2
A      B        [[1, 2], [4, 4]]
B      C                [[2, 3]]
Name: mounth, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks , actually I need this form of interval to create a dynamic graph .

Comment: @sunny I can not guarantee the speed, but this should work for your sample example