# Create pandas series of intervals from pandas series of values

Tags: pandas

The closest answer I can find seems too complex: [How I can create an interval column in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47396828/575530)

If I had a pandas data frame that looked like this:

```
+-------+
| Value |
+-------+
|     6 |
|    12 |
|    56 |
|    60 |
|   120 |
+-------+
```

How might I turn it into this?

```
+-------+-----------+
| Value | Interval  |
+-------+-----------+
|     6 |           |
|    12 | (6, 12]   |
|    56 | (12, 56]  |
|    60 | (56, 60]  |
|   120 | (60, 120] |
+-------+-----------+
```

(N.B. This is a very simplified example, my real data-frame is big and so performance is an issue.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html)** defaults to `right=True` so if `'Value'` is strictly monotonically increasing

```
df['Interval'] = pd.cut(df.Value, bins=df.Value)
#   Value       Interval
#0      6            NaN
#1     12    (6.0, 12.0]
#2     56   (12.0, 56.0]
#3     60   (56.0, 60.0]
#4    120  (60.0, 120.0]
```

Comment: I cannot see how to use this on the elements in a group, but I'll ask that as [a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59760936/575530).